# balanced-payments How a user can update their credit card information?

Tags: balanced-payments

If a user wants to update expiration date, can they do that? I tried using updateCard, but it only allows me to update 'meta' information but I intend to change expiration_year or expiration_month.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new `card`, and then mark the previous one as invalid. You can’t write any changes to card details after a card has been created. (Your user is going to have to re-enter all of their card information.) Hope that helps.